# Checking if a range object is in a List

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I have created a list of Range objects in C#

```
private List<Excel.Range> _dataCells = new List<Excel.Range>();
```

If am currently adding a reange to the list using the following:

```
if (_dataCells.Contains(_excel.Selection) == false)
{
    _dataCells.Add(_excel.Selection);
}
```

This ends up with a List that has duplicate values. How can I use the Contains method on a List of complex types?

Comment: **Hi, you cant try with this post:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489258/linqs-distinct-on-a-particular-property

Comment: What are you trying to do? The root problem is that `Range` does not have equality defined, but it's unclear what the purpose of having a list of ranges is to know what the right approach is? Should you keep a list of strings that _represent_ the ranges instad? Or a `Dictionary<String, Range>`)?

Comment: What I am trying to do is get a list of unique ranges that I could then loop through and perform further actions on. I previously has a Dictionary as you propose but I was hoping using a List would make everything more concise.

Comment: @Domronic The problem is that two ranges created from the same reference are different objects, so `Contains` will not detect duplicates. If you can use the reference (e.g. `"A1:B2"`) as a string key then a `Dictionary` will probably be better for performance as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `Contains` function, you could use the `All` function and check the relevant properties to decide if it's an existing item.

```
if (_dataCells.All(x => x.Selection.Property != _excel.Selection.Property))
{
    _dataCells.Add(_excel.Selection);
}
```

Another way to solve this, is to implement the `Equals` function. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/generate-equals-gethashcode-methods?view=vs-2019) for some more explanation.

```
public class Selection : IEquatable<Selection>
{
    ...

    public override bool Equals(Selection selection)
    {
        return selection != null && this.Property == selection.Property;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would caution that this method has a lot of COM property calls and may have terrible performance if called a lot.